# GLM translation issue

Tags: c++, matrix, 3d, transformation, glm-math

I have a model and want to move it along its axes, if I have a transformation matrix `glm::mat4` and the up vector is `glm::vec4 up(matrix[1]);` so if i wanna move the model along the up vector by value `up*=d;` then `matrix=glm::translate(matrix,up);` , the result matrix doesn't move the model right, for example if the up vector id `(0,0.707106769,0.707106769)` "the model is rotated around the X axis by 45d" and i want to move it by 5 units so the translation vector is (0,3.535533845,3.535533845) then after the translation the position component changed in Y only so it is moved along Y axis only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLM's source code for `translate`:

```
template<typename T, qualifier Q>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER mat<4, 4, T, Q> translate(mat<4, 4, T, Q> const& m, vec<3, T, Q> const& v)
{
    mat<4, 4, T, Q> Result(m);
    Result[3] = m[0] * v[0] + m[1] * v[1] + m[2] * v[2] + m[3];
    return Result;
}
```

The effect of the applied translation is modified by the rotational component (top-left 3x3 sub-matrix, or the first 3 columns if the bottom row is `0 0 0 1`) of the existing matrix, i.e.:

> `glm::translate` **prepends**, rather than **appends**, the translation.

In other words, the above code is equivalent to:

```
// create an identity matrix and apply the translation
glm::mat4 translation = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.f), up);

// post-multiply (i.e. the applied translation comes FIRST)
matrix = matrix * translation;
```

The desired effect you want can be achieved with:

```
1)

// pre-multiply (i.e. the applied translation comes AFTER)
matrix = translation * matrix;
```

Or equivalently, construct the translation in the model's *local* basis:

```
2)

// local up vector (Y-axis)
glm::vec3 local_up(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
local_up *= d;

// apply using translate as before
matrix = glm::translate(matrix, local_up);
```